# Android Studio: app-release.apk installation takes forever

Tags: android, installation, apk

I developed an Android App with Android Studio 2.0 (stable).

For debugging I used a Blackberry Priv with Android 6.0.1 - all working perfectly.

Now I wanted to test the App on other devices, namely an Xperia Z2, Xperia Z, Xperia Z1 compact or a Z3 tablet compact.

For this I sent the app-debug.apk or the signed app-release.apk to these devices and wanted to install it.

The installation starts and asks for the permissions and when I start the installation process on any of these devices the installation takes forever. There is no error message but not even after about half an hour the installation has finished.

I re-built the project several times, restarted Android Studio and (as already mentioned) tried this on several devices - still no success.

Bug in Android Studio or what am I doing wrong?